Reprint a theorem's picture after page turn
I'm working on a hyperbolic geometry document that involves long proofs often based on a single figure. Sometimes these proofs run on to several pages. I would like LaTeX to reprint the theorem's picture after every time the reader turns the page so that the reader doesn't have to keep flipping back to the picture while reading. Is there a way to automate this?
Edit: Here's a MWE
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}


\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    A complicated, unintuitive theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
    Consider the following diagram the entire time you are reading this proof.

    \begin{figure} [h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        \label{fig:enter-label}
    \end{figure}

\kant[1-8]
    
\end{proof}

\end{document}


Start by providing us a MWE.

The oddity here is that the float is independent of the proof environment. And, remember, it's all-or-nothing. So, if you have (say) 2 lines of a proof on a new page, the automation would include another (duplicate) image. What should happen with the figure numbering? All of this to say... why not just add the odd figure here-or-there manually?

Sure, I could add the figures manually. But then if I move things around I have to adjust all the figures in the whole document. And it's not just the odd figure here or there, it's a common occurrence in this document and in lots of geometry texts. I do think you are right that it would be great if latex were smart enough not to add the figures again for two new lines (or even for an adjustable number of lines).
